# I'm having problems with what I "sed"

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to replace the port in this config but I'm having issues with it basically ignoring me.  What have I done wrong here?

Showing the line I wish to replace.

```
b@a:/home/mse1# cat server.properties |grep port
server-port=33333
```

Then showing you the sed I used in several other scripts to do the exact same thing thusly failing to accomplish the task.

```
b@a:/home/mse1# sed 's/server-port=.*`\n`/server-port=33334/g' /home/mse1/server.properties |grep server-port
server-port=33333
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you (correctly) used single quotes, the back-quotes are seen by `sed` simply as a part of the pattern.  Also, `\n` doesn't mean newline in that context — you use `$` to look for the end of the line.  Hence:

```
sed 's/^server-port=.*$/server-port=33334/' …
```

You don't need the `g` modifier when there's only going to be one match on a line, as there is when you have `^` at the start and `$` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

try this below code

```
sed -i.bak s/server-port=33333/server-port=33334/g /home/mse1/server.properties
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but it doesn't use wildcards to match the port number whereas the original did. Although with this `s///` command the single quotes are not strictly necessary, it is generally good practice to use single quotes around the `sed` script (or expressions in the `sed` script if you use multiple `-e '...command...'` options).  The `g` modifier isn't really needed; there won't be lines in the file that contain two copies of `server-port=33333` on the one line. Using `-i.bak` is good (GNU and BSD `sed` support it, but BSD `sed` requires the suffix whereas GNU `sed` makes it optional).